# php and Ajax : Display sub category automatically when i select main category

Tags: php, ajax

PHP Ajax :
i used two tables

1. main Category
2. Sub Category

main Category table contains, main category list  like MOBILE, COMPUTER...etc
Sub Category table contains, sub_category related to Main Category like Sim card, Temper glass, Charger...etc
when i select main category, sub category must automatically display all the sub category related to selected Main category in drop down box
example:
Main Category : Mobile
Sub Category : sim card, temper glass, data cable...etc
please help

```
    <div id="main-cat">
       <select>
         <option></option>
         <option></option>
         <option></option>
      </select>
     </div>
    <div id="sub-cat">
      <select>
         <option></option>
         <option></option>
         <option></option>
      </select
    </div>
```

Comment: This is way too broad a question to answer on SO.  Have a good attempt yourself using one of the many online guides to doing this very thing, and come back with some specified questions if you get stuck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to start with some tutorials and examples and make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem regarding the code you've written, we can help with that specific problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.